# Menu Exception while tracking

Tags: cocoa

I have a serious exception thrown in 10.6, whereas everything is fine in 10.7. When calling action to menuitem the below log is generated. Please let me know why the following exception is thrown.

Regards,
iSight

```
23/04/12 6:26:15 PM MyApp[155]  *** Assertion failure in -[NSComboBoxCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1038.36/AppKit.subproj/NSCell.m:1531 
23/04/12 6:26:15 PM MyApp[155]  Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil 
23/04/12 6:26:25 PM MyApp[155]  HIToolbox: ignoring exception '*** -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: NSFont)' that raised inside Carbon event dispatch 
 CoreFoundation                      0x99f3a6ca __raiseError + 41
   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x945e55a9 objc_exception_throw + 5
   CoreFoundation                      0x99f3a3f8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 13
   CoreFoundation                     0x99f3a36a +[NSException raise:format:] + 5
   Foundation           0x9469d3eb -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:] + 26
   MyApp        0x000883df 0x0 + 55804
   MyApp                              0x000033d0 0x0 + 1326
   MyApp                              0x00029cf6 0x0 + 17125
   AppKit                              0x97443a26 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 11
   AppKit      0x974438d9 -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 43
0  AppKit          0x974435ca -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 17
1  AppKit        0x974434b6 -[NSMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:] + 6
2  AppKit     0x97443469 -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 5
3  AppKit                              0x974433cf -[NSMenuItem
_internalPerformActionThroughMenuIfPossible] + 9
4  AppKit                              0x97443313 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl
_carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 33
5  AppKit                              0x97437a55 NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 40
6  HIToolbox                  0x90acac2f
_ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec
+ 156
7  HIToolbox                           0x90ac9ef6 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec
+ 41
8  HIToolbox                           0x90aec7f3 SendEventToEventTarget + 5
9  HIToolbox                           0x90b18e87
_ZL18SendHICommandEventmPK9HICommandmmhPKvP20OpaqueEventTargetRefS5_PP14OpaqueEventRef
+ 44
0  HIToolbox                           0x90b3db90 SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 6
1  HIToolbox             0x90b3db47 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 12
2  HIToolbox              0x90b3da5d _ZL19FinishMenuSelectionP13SelectionDataP10MenuResultS2_ + 15
3  HIToolbox                           0x90cbf364
_ZL19PopUpMenuSelectCoreP8MenuData5PointdS1_tjPK4RecttmS4_S4_PK10__CFStringPP13OpaqueMenuRefPt
+ 185
4  HIToolbox                           0x90cbf6bb _HandlePopUpMenuSelection7 + 67
5  AppKit                              0x976cf6e6 _NSSLMPopUpCarbonMenu3 + 393
6  AppKit                   0x976cfa76 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl
_popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:withFont:] + 22
7  AppKit                              0x97848945 -[NSMenu _popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:withFont:] + 27
8  AppKit                              0x978489e4 -[NSMenu
_popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:] + 6
9  AppKit                              0x978487b7 -[NSMenu _popUpMenuWithEvent:forView:] + 5
0  AppKit     0x97a3f65d -[NSView rightMouseDown:] + 10
1  AppKit                 0x97730d1b -[NSControl _rightMouseUpOrDown:] + 53
2  AppKit         0x9751ab28 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 575
3  AppKit                   0x9743360b -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 643
4  AppKit              0x973c7253 -[NSApplication run] + 91
5  AppKit                      0x973bf289 NSApplicationMain + 57
6  MyApp                          0x00002a45 0x0 + 1082
7  ???                                 0x00000002 0x0 + 2 ) 
23/04/12 6:26:37 PM MyApp[155]  NSMenu received exception *** -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: NSFont) during menu tracking.  The exception will be ignored. 
23/04/12 6:26:37 PM Dynamo[155] *** -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: NSFont)
```

Comment: It would really help to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

In NSDictionary object you can not setting **nil** value